# Is there an easy way to combine raw SCSS files into a single file based on @imports?

Tags: webpack, sass, gulp, shopify

Shopify doesn't fully support @imports, unfortunately.

Is there an easy way—using Webpack or similar—to concatenate/combine all @import files into a single SCSS file without processing?

I.e., by looping through all @imports and outputting a single file.

Comment: Why not produce your own ultimate css file. Seems like if you've mastered SCSS and imports galore locally, you have that asset at you disposal for production use.

Comment: Are you processing your SCSS files on your website?That should be done on localhost then only the CSS file sent up to the net

Comment: I want to use SCSS on Shopify because I need to use liquid in the stylesheet for settings. So, I need to concatenate/combine all the Bootstrap files into a single SCSS file locally, to use on Shopify, which compiles it to CSS before serving to the site. I have done this with Webpack where it loops through and compiles based on @imports—but it's a bit ugly and I wondered if there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do that using gulp and the gulp-scss-combine package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-scss-combine

e.g.

```
function styles() {
  return gulp.src("styles.scss")
    .pipe(combine())
    .pipe(concat('styles.scss.liquid'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(assets))
}
```

styles.scss has all the import rules e.g.

```
@import "partials/header";
@import "partials/main";
@import "partials/footer";
```

file structure is like this

```
/assets
  styles.scss
  styles.scss.liquid
  /partials
    _header.scss.liquid
    _main.scss.liquid
    _footer.scss.liquid
```